# Voting app in rails 3: how do I link to vote method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, models, erb

To teach myself Rails, im building an extremely simple Voting app.

There are 2 models, Question and Option. Question has_many Options and Option belongs_to Question.

Using the standard scaffolding, I have reached a stage where you can add a question, view it, and add options to it and see these options.

What I would like to do now is add the code that increases an option.count value by one when clicking on a link.  I have a vote_up method in the Option model:

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :text, :presence => :true
  belongs_to :question

  def vote_up
    self.count += 1
  end
end
```

My Options controller looks like:

```
class OptionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @option = @question.options.create(params[:option])
    redirect_to question_path(@question)
  end

end
```

My Question model looks like:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :text, :presence => {:message => 'A question normally has text...'}
  has_many :options, :dependent => :destroy


  def vote
    # Maybe the vote code will go here???
  end
end
```

And my Question controller has the usual new, create, edit, destroy methods that the scaffold creates. V little customisation here.

My show.html.erb view where I would like to put the link to the vote method looks like:

```
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p>
      <b>Question <%= @question.guid %></b>:
      <%= @question.text %>
    </p>
    <% if @question.options.count == 0 %>
        <p>Shame! there are currently no options to vote on. Add some! </p>
    <% elsif @question.options.count == 1 %>
        <p>One option in a vote is a dictatorship... Maybe add some more?</p>
    <% end %>
    <h2>Options:</h2>
    <% @question.options.each do |option| %>
      <p>
        <%= option.text %>:  ** Link to vote here!
      </p>
    <% end %>

    <h2>Add an option to vote on</h2>
    <%= form_for([@question, @question.options.build]) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :text %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :text %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <% if @question.options.count == 0 # Only show edit if no options saved. %> 
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(@question) %> |
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', questions_path %>
```

So what I am trying to do is add a "vote" link next to each option that calls the vote_up method in the options model. This is probably laughably easy, but i've hit a wall and would really appreciate any help.

Also, any suggestions on how to do this better would be welcome!

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @oded-harth has showed a right way, but I have two remarks:

First of all, Rails is a beautiful language and is written to simplify our developer lives ;) When programming in Rails you must never forget that. With this in mind, I want to point you to ["increment()" method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/75015d1b5cae80826ef41add3c84d1dd51fee259/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L146). So you can simply up-vote without unnecessary `+= 1`. To down-vote use `decrement()`. I believe you can use it like this: `option.increment(:count)`

Second, I think it's a little dirty to have a whole `form` for a simple vote action. You can use something like this

```
<%= link_to "Vote Up", :url => { :action => :vote_up, :option_id => option.id }, :method => :put %>
```

To make it work you'll have to set your route something like this:

```
resources :votes
  put :vote_up
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Getting closer. Now when I click on the vote link i get taken to http://localhost:3000/questions/9?method=put&url[action]=vote_up&url[option_id]=1 which is the current page with params appended..... Also, did you mean resources: options instead of resources: votes ? I have put the vote_up method in the questions controller. Thanks again!

Comment: I forgot to mention that this approach works if you have working Javascript libraries in your project, such as jQuery-UJS, for example, or Scriptaculous and Prototype that are by default included with rails project in "public/javascripts".

You also might want to define inherited routes:

`resources :questions do
    resources :options do # yes I mean options ;)
      put :vote_up
      put :vote_down
    end
  end`

then take a look to your routes with `rake routes` and find `PUT questions/:question_id/options/:id/vote_up`. then use it's URL method instead of `:url => {...}`

Comment: By the way, `vote_up` method goes into the `OptionsController` because you are changing the `Option` model by increasing/decreasing it's value by 1.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is make the vote_up method in the controller:

```
def vote_up 

option = Option.find(params[:option_id])
option.count += 1

redirect (to where do you want...)

end
```

And in the view I would call that method this way:

```
<%= form_for( option, :url => { :action => "vote_up", :option_id => option.id} ) do |f| %>
<%= f.submit("vote up") %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just to clarify- you mean in the Option controller?